# Failed to start the following executable,

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, jcreator

Failed to start the following executable, \bin\javac.exe -g -classpath C:\Users\user\Documents -d C:\Users\user\Documents C:\Users\user\Documents\Kwame.java For help, please refer to http://www.jcreator.com/installation.htm.

For some reason it keeps doing this no matter what code I write and I have no idea why.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class KyeretwieTestProgram1113 {
    public KyeretwieTestProgram1113() {
        Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in)
        System.out.println(Enter the high temperature on day 1:);
        double d = kbInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Enter the high temperature on day 2:);
        double da = kbInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Enter the high temperature on day 3:);
        double a = kbInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Enter the high temperature on day 4:);
        double day = kbInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Enter the high temperature on day 5:);
        double y = kbInput.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you've installed JCreator wrong.  I think you should refer to http://www.jcreator.com/installation.htm, like it says.  People here on Stack Overflow can't really check your installation for you.  There are limits on our powers.

Answer (score 1):

The error shown is not related to the code but rather the Java compiler or javac. Make sure you have the JDK installed and can run a simple 'Hello world' program before slapping code here.